# Return value from nested function in JS

Tags: javascript

Super beginner here, I read the similar questions asked here and it did not solve my problem.

I know the instructions say that I'm only supposed to amend the final line (var burger...), but I cannot get this one to pass.

```
var food = function() {
  return function() {
    return "HAMBURGER"
  }
}

var burger = food();
```

I want to return "HAMBURGER" but instead I return [Function]

Comment: try `food()()` - your function returns a function, so you need to invoke them both

Comment: Why do you use a closure? You don't need one here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: You are already know how to call a function (`f()`). You know that calling `food` *returns a function*.... btw, what changes have you made to the last line so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do if you are only supposed to change the bottom line is to change it to:

```
var burger = food()();
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
var burgerFunction = food();
var burger = burgerFunction();
```

Your function returns a function, so you need to invoke them both

Answer (score 3):

As the function `food` returns an anonymous function, it has to be invoke to run and produce some result:

```js
var food = function() {
  return function() {
    return "HAMBURGER"
  }
}

var burger = food()(); // or food().call()
console.log(burger)
```

An interesting article about different ways of function invocation could be found [here](https://codeplanet.io/javascript-apply-vs-call-vs-bind/).

Answer (score 0):

The same solution but with better code.

1. If you are going to have a nameless function, I'd suggest using an arrow function.
2. `var food = function() { ...` is identical to `function food() { ...`
3. "Self-invoke a function" using `(<Function>)()`.

Here's your new code:

```js
function food() {
  return (() => {
    return "HAMBURGER"
  })();
}

food(); // "HAMBURGER"
```

Instead of return a regular function, we return and immediately